# python)How can I calculate difference between two times in mininute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried it by this way

```
time1=input("Enter your first time (ex.xx:xxPM) : ")
am_or_pm1=time1[-2:].upper()
colpos1=time1[2:3]
hour1=time1[0:2]
minute1=time1[3:5]
print('This is your first time')
print(time1)

time2=input("Enter your first time (ex.xx:xxPM) : ")
am_or_pm2=time2[-2:].upper()
colpos2=time2[2:3]
hour2=time2[0:2]
minute2=time2[3:5]
print('This is your second time')
print(time2)

timediff=(time1 - time2)
print(timediff)
```

but there is too many prob such as cannot calculate between PM and AM and also

i cant use - with str.

I don't know how to use the module for now so anyone can help me? :C
I took more than 12 hours for this and tried to find the help at the Google but
all of the samples are using the module ... help me!!

Comment: Look at `time`, `date` and `timedelta`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `datetime` objects for this:

```
from datetime import datetime

time1=input("Enter your first time (ex.xx:xxPM) : ")
timeObj1 = datetime.strptime(time1,'%I:%M%p')

time2=input("Enter your first time (ex.xx:xxPM) : ")
timeObj2 = datetime.strptime(time2,'%I:%M%p')

print(timeObj1-timeObj2)
```

## Sample Input:

```
Enter your first time (ex.xx:xxPM) : 5:30PM
Enter your first time (ex.xx:xxPM) : 5:00PM
0:30:00
```

Comment: Do i have to use that? Is there noway to find it without the import???Anyway thank you XD

Comment: If you want to rewrite the wheel, you can; I'd just not recommend it as it leads to very difficult to read code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need more study for the language anyway.. :C have a good day

Comment: You're welcome!  If you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.  And here's a reference I use http://strftime.org/ for datetime.